# Simpler Seq.unfold in F#

Tags: f#, sequences, seq

Is there a simpler `Seq.unfold` version that just takes the previous element as the state? I know you can easily adapt `Seq.unfold` to do that, but the result is not very readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a built-in function that does that.

Repeating the same pattern using `Seq.unfold` would be quite annoying, but you can easily use `unfold` to define a function that behaves as you want and then just use the new function:

```
module Seq = 
  let generate f v = 
    Seq.unfold (fun v -> let r = f v in Some(r, r)) v
```

As an aside, if I wanted to implement the pattern, I would probably go with a simple recursive sequence expression, which might be easier to read than using `Seq.unfold`. The `generate` function can be implemented like this:

```
let rec generate f v = seq {
  yield v
  yield! generate f (f v) }
```

This behaves a bit differently, because it yields the first value as well. Not sure what behaviour you want.

Answer (score 2):

Tomas' answer is good but, like you said, using `Seq.unfold` to do this is ugly, and, as he said, his `generate` function behaves differently.

If you want the same behavior as `Seq.unfold`, but using the previous element as state, this should do it:

```ml
let rec unfold f state = 
  seq {
    match f state with
    | Some x ->
      yield x
      yield! unfold f x
    | None -> ()
  }
```